# change filter name in Magento from 'category' to the name of the parent category

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

On a layered category view the list of sub-categories is titled 'Category' (as seen here: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/bed-and-bath), I would like it to instead be titled with the name of the parent category (if it has a parent, other than the root category).

So in the example at the above link, rather than being:

```
CATEGORY
-- Living Room
-- Bedroom
```

it would be:

```
FURNITURE
-- Living Room
-- Bedroom
```

My main issue seems to be figuring out how to access the category model from within the Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View as `$this->getCurrentCategory()` doesn't seem to work.

Using Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current category is stored in the Magento registry under the key `current_category`.  You can access this value by calling:

```
$current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

For completeness, you can set values in the registry using `Mage::register('mykey', $myvalue)`.

The templates of interest to (I think) are under `template/catalog/layer`.  Don't quote me though.  You should switch on template hints to double check.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately `<?php echo  Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>` returns nothing for me.. Any ideas why?

Comment: Aha nevermind, the object is returned but I obviously need to call `getName()` as well. Thanks again!